# Excess rows appear in DataGridView after apply TreeView Filter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

There is a problem with displaying rows after applying the filter. In the DataGridView I use dynamic update.

Description of the problem:
After applying the filter (by condition `Rows.Visible = true` or `Rows.Visible = false`), other rows appear, while not the whole new line is displayed, but only its updated cells, as in image:

[image: problem image]

It is important to note that table updates do not occur in the main thread; Updating occurs at a fixed interval `thread_delay_time`.

Code `TreeView1_AfterSelect`:

```
private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    Classes.TreeViewFilter treeViewFilter = new Classes.TreeViewFilter();
    treeViewFilter.Filter(this);
}
```

Part of the class `TreeViewFilter`:

```
class TreeViewFilter
    {
        public void Filter(MainForm mainForm)
        {
            switch (mainForm.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
            {
                case "Category":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "MED":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 1)
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        else
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Air":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 2)
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

... etc.

Filtering is required not only by the method `After_Select`, but also dynamic (with the selected node `TreeView` only the desired set of rows is displayed). Implementation through method `DataGridView1_CellValueChanged` and new thread `private void ThreeViewMarker()`:

```
 Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                switch (TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
                {
                    case "Category":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                    CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                    currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "MED":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 1)
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Air":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 2)
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                        }
```

... etc.

This method also does not work as it should by analogy with the previous method.

There is still incomprehensible behavior of the form as a whole, a problem when scaling the window (the first line from the set appears):

[image: scaling]

In the .gif, the method with dynamic updating of the `DataGridView` **is disabled**! The result of a simple method `After_Select`.

Please tell me how to deal with this. What did I not take into account?

.gif description:

- Категория - category
- МЭД - Equivalent dose (in ru *Мощность эквивалентной дозы*)
- Воздух - Air
- Спец. контроль - special control
- Не работает - Not working
- Уставки - threshold
- Предаварийная - pre accident
- Аварийная - accident

To solve the problem, I tried using this:

```
string columnName = "type"; // or other column
string filterValue = "2";   // or other value
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, filterValue);
(mainForm.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

But in this case, hidden rows are no longer interrogated (they seem to be missing from DataSource or something like that)

Thanks for the help; I apologize for my English ... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem.

[problem.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxggp.gif)

The extra row is the row that is selected in the CurencyManager and highlighted by a triangle.

Solution options:

- Disable CurrencyManager at the beginning of the filtering method

  ```
  CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext [dataGridView1.DataSource];
  currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
  ```

  Header's triangle will disappear (but then it will not work to use CurrentRow and CurrentCell in some cases and maybe something else).
- Switch the row to the one that should be visible.

  ```
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[columnNumber, visibleRowNumber];
  ```

  But this does not work in the case when all rows should be hidden.

[solution.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtca7.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Add a Visibility Property to your BindingSource and bind the
  visibility of each row to the Visibility Property.
- Disable    RaiseListChangedEvents and renable them after, and also
  reset    bindings so that the grid knows to update itself.

  CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager) BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];

  currencyManager.RaiseListChangedEvents = **false**;

  *//Disable all other rows by setting the visibility property to false in the binding source*

  currencyManager.RaiseListChangedEvents = **true**;

  currencyManager.**ResetBindings**();

Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Use the DataBindingComplete Event to disable/enable rows

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

How can I add a visibility property to a BindingSource and bind a row visibility property to it?

CurrencyManager does not have methods (RaiseListChangedEvents, ResetBindings), but the BindingSource has these methods

Comment: before I dive too deep in that have you tried Refresh on your DataGrid?

Comment: or Invalidate ?

Comment: I tried the dataGridView1.Update(); and dataGridView1.Refresh();. It did not bring any results.